# Easyphp Devserver 16.1 Phpmyadmin

Tags: easyphp

I had install Easyphp Devserver 16.1 on a fresh W10 installation.
I didn't use easyphp for a long time and i'm confuse, i can't access to phpmyadmin as i do before (EasyPHP 5.4.6) via a right click on the taskbar icon of easyphp.
Is there a way to access phpmyadmin with EasyPHP Devserver 16.1 ?

Thanks
PS : Sorry for my poor english ;)

Answer (score 5):

@seagram points in the right direction, just don't forget to go back to dashboard after having started the http server (I was searching the modules section on apache page).

Here are the steps to access phpmyadmin from the dashboard :

- Right click on Easyphp icon in the toolbar
- Click Dashboard
- Start HTTP server and DB Server
- Go back to the Dashboard
- Click on "Open" in the "Modules" section next to "MySql administration:phpmyadmin" in the lower side of the page

It should open phpmyadmin.

[DevServer dashboard with open button activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZi9s.png)

Answer (score 4):

The bomproof solution:

1. [Download](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) PHPMyAdmin from [its original website](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)
2. Unpack it and
3. Put somewhere into eds-www (for ex. \eds-www\phpmyadmin)
4. Now you can access it by url (localhost/phpmyadmin) after mysql and apache are started

Comment: What is the username and password?

Answer (score 3):

The steps to follow is very easy. 
1. Go to your task bar and right click on the easyPHP Icon. Thats if you asked the installer to put the icon there, otherwise. Go to program files and look for easyPHP icon and right click on it. Then select Open Dashboard.

2. From there click on start to start the the HTTP Server.
3. Select Apache Server as your server and select your preferred port. Now the latest version has option to choose the port you want to use, in the event that there are other service(s) using port 8080.
4. After doing this then go to your browser and enter the directory of your phpmyadmin index.php preceded by localhost or 127.0.0.1. For example:

127.0.0.1:8080/eds-modules/phpmyadmin4551x160516133840/index.php

This should work without any hassles.

Answer (score 0):

I am discovering the new EasyPHP 16.1 myself. All that changes are confusing.
However, answer is easy: One has to right-click on the TaskBar icon, and choose "Dashboard".

It opens a page in the browser, where one has to start at least the Database server, in order to see an "Open" button in the right side of the "MySQL Administration" row in the "MODULES" section.

As long as the database server is stopped, the button will not show (logical indeed).

Hopes this helps.

Comment: I did it. But still i see a blank screen. I use W8 and got eclipse installed for android development in the same system

Answer (score 0):

easyphp devserver 16.1 running on Windows 10

hello everybody,
I am new to this new version of easyphp.

I tried dashboard > start database server (the default 5.7.10 one)> 
but no 'modules' section, thence, no 'open' button

still searching

Comment: following last post: Tried Xampp, error messages are more clear.   I tried to change the default ports of apache>config>httpd.conf and controlpanel>config>services>apache from 80 to 8080 following some advice.   Now apache runs but not Tomcat.   Other ports to be used?

Answer (score 0):

I installed devserver 17 on win10. To connect to your websites/projects just enter: 127.0.0.1/phpinfo.php

127.0.0.1:1111 (the default didn't work) neither does :0808

Answer (score 0):

1. Start "HTTP Server" & then "Database Server".
2. You can see down there PhpMyAdmin module having button on right side "Open". Click on Open button and it will launch MySQL Admin.