# laravel migration: unknown database

Tags: php, mysql, database, migration

I am new to the whole thing of php and laravel. I followed a tuto on internet. and I was trying to create table named "links", but, I got this error:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'createlinkstable'
```

this is the file "database.php":

```
<?php

return [

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'CreateLinksTable'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],


],

'migrations' => 'migrations',

'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],
],

];
```

and this is the file ".env"

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=*******
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=CreateLinksTable
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

It's when I try to execute this command "php artisan migrate" that I got the error bellow

Should I create the database `CreateLinksTable` manually? If yes,how?

N.B: I am using easyphp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTOzx.png)

I was reading this post, but it's not helping ([Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756194/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-using-password-yes))

Comment: People, please learn how PHP and MySQL works before working with Laravel... Yes you need to create that database, you can with `phpmyadmin` and I dont think that `CreateLinksTable` should be a databse.. its more like laravel migration name...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, the problem I was facing is that I couldn't access phpmyadmin to create database (127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin) wasn't working so instead I used (http://127.0.0.1/eds-modules/phpmyadmin4531x161221110224/index.php )
this post helped me a lot : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505761/easyphp-devserver-16-1-phpmyadmin)